# Listening to mic over speakers (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: sound, microphone, volume-control

I have a little problem here. I was using an option in Windows called Listen to this device (in audio tab in control panel) and I was able to listen to microphone (in my case that was a bassguitar) and if  I stopped playing the bassguitar I simply turned the volume down of the microphone - but the mic was functioning when I was talking on TeamSpeak, etc... 
When I do turn down the volume of microphone on Ubuntu it stops working entirely to the moment, when I get the volume back up. It is kind of annoying because when I am talking on TeamSpeak I have to hear myself through speakers -_- 
Can anyone help me please how can I just turn down the volume so I will not hear what I am saying but the microphone will still work properly? And when I plug in my bassguitar I will turn on my volume and I will hear the bassguitar?

I would really love, as I did in Windows, to listen my bassguitar in high quality through the PC using Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!